# batch make email link as image

Tags: html, email, spam-prevention

Is there a way that could convert all `mailto:example@exapmle.com` email links in a html page to images showing same content/email address (I didn't have reputation to post images, [an example image](http://safemail.justlikeed.net/e/31b0869643a304b81e28002c41de012d.png) ). I knew some website provide such kind of service, but it could be done one by one. I have a webpage have many email links, so want to ask a better or smarter way to do that.

Any response would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  One way to do this is using PHP.  Basically, what you are describing is writing text to an image.  This can be done using the PHP imagettftext() function.  See http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php for more info.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response. I know a little about PHP, but I will try. Thanks again. If anyone would have a js/jquery example, would be even great.